# is there a way to include en and ar in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to send email through node.js server and using ejs template. I want to send some Arabic text with moment() date formatting. But the alignment of date is not correct. Can anyone suggest me the solution, tried "direction: rtl;" but still problem exists.

The text says your order has been scheduled for <:time:>

```
كرا لاختيارك بيتزا هت! تمت جدولة طلبك في <%= moment(order.advanceTime).utcOffset(120).format('D MMM, YYYY [|] h:mm:ss A') %>
```

```
css: <td class="para1" style="padding-bottom: 20px; direction: rtl;">
كرا لاختيارك بيتزا هت! تمت جدولة طلبك في <%= moment(order.advanceTime).utcOffset(120).format('D MMM, YYYY [|] h:mm:ss A') %>
</td>
```

The alignment is incorrect

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it, I was giving `direction:rtl` to parent table.
removed and added date in a span tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your date format :

```js
console.log(moment().utcOffset(120).format('D MMM, YYYY [|] h:mm:ss A'))

console.log(moment().utcOffset(120).format('A ss:mm:h [|] YYYY MMM D'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

You could also take a look at [this section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) of moment.js documentation which treats internationalization.

Comment: i want the same date format DD:MM:YYYY | H:MM:SS", but the rest of text in arabic.

Comment: @Anand can you give an example of what you would like to obtain ? It's not clear to me